# How to send and receive "&" with $_GET and $_POST?

Tags: php, api, post, get

I have to show list of courses and their information and when users click on the course name, they will be directed to another page which shows more details for that course. 
So I am using $_GET and $_POST.

So this is part of the code in my first file:

```
  <tbody>
            <?php foreach($courses as $data1)  
        { 
           $temp=html_entity_decode($data1['title']);

          $send= ($data1['prefix'] . "," . $temp);  

           ?>
             <tr class="<?php echo ($i%2) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">               
               <td><a href="course_details.php?course=<?php echo $send?>"><?php echo $data1['title'];?></a></td>    
               <td> <?php echo $data1['prefix']; ?> </td>
               <td><?php echo $data1['number'];?></td>

             </tr>

    <?php $i++;} }?>


              </tbody>
```

You can see in part my of code I have used html_entity_decode, and that is because I am working with API and information returned by this API will be structured in a JSON format. So if I have a course with a title which has & in it, like "Systems Planning & Implementation", then I can search for it.(I have a search option, so users can search for a course in the list of the courses they see)
 Using html_entity_decode has solved the problem. 
In my other file I use

```
 $course_details=$_GET['course'];
```

to receive the data send by the other file. In order to make sure I have received the right data, I use

```
echo $course_details;
```

But I found out for a course like "Systems Planning & Implementation", what the other file receives   is "Systems Planning", So I still have problem with & , and $_Get does not send "&" or $_POST does not receive "&".

So do you have any suggestion that how can I solve the problem?

Comment: It has to be urlencoded.  `course=<?php echo urlencode($send);?>` Otherwise, the `&` is interpreted as a delimiter and will populate another key in `$_GET` called `$_GET[' Implementation']`